# Cannot use ArtOfTest.WebAii.Core

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm trying to write down a test on C# using Nunit and ArtOfTest, I added the appropriate references and when I write down "using ArtOfTest.WebAii.Core" and tried to build the solution (even with no code), this error is returned 
***(The type or namespace name 'ArtOfTest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))***

Would you please show me how to proceed? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: What "appropriate references" did you add, and where?

Comment: I meant ArtOfTest.WebAii and nunit.framework references

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the project, probably it will be `ArtOfTest.WebAii.dll`, in order for the `using ArtOfTest.WebAii.Core` to be satisfied.

On your project, Right Click > Add Reference > Browse to where ArtOfTest.WebAii.dll is and click ok.

See the documentation here for more details: http://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/user-guide/getting-started/using-telerik-testing-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and what solved it for me is editing the project file 
from ToolsVersion="**4.0**" 
to ToolsVersion="**2.0**"

I hope this helps :)